# Insert a string to 2D array at a specified index in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing, insert

I suppose I should explain my problem in a matrix.

I would like to receive from this:

```
A=[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

this one:

```
 A=[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **h**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [ 0, 0, 0, **h**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Bold letters only highlight the problem. I have tried:

```
def r(i):
    for k in i[-1:-4:-2]:
        for l in k[3:6:2]:
            k[l]='h'
    print (i)
r(A)
```

but it returns:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
['**h**', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
['**h**', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

which definitely doesn't suit my expectations. I want to insert strings at the specified indexes by 2 steps from the last element of the list of lists (the last list), starting from a certain index of rhe row. Could you help me?

As you asked, I add another example:
basic array:

```
B=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

output:

```
B=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, !, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, !, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, !, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Tag the language this is too? Also, it’s kinda hard to work out what you want. Maybe give the output you do want so we can compare

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
def r(i, substitution, col_start, row_stop):
    for row, R in enumerate(i):
        found = False
        for col, el in enumerate(R):
            if not found and col >= (col_start + (len(i)-1) - row) and \
                    (col % 2 == col_start % 2) and row > row_stop and \
                    (row % 2 == (len(i)-1) % 2):
                found = True
                i[row][col] = substitution
    return i
A=[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
B=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
r(A, 'h', 3, 1)
r(B, '!', 1, 2)

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'h', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 'h', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '!', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, '!', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, '!', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Remind that if you need to perform such modifications to the code or you're having fun or your design has to be modified. Keep it simple!

Comment: Notice that this function is exactly adapted to the problem you're trying to solve and it's not portable. You can try to make it like that, though.